# Matrix dimensions must agree MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am using a model.p file as a function in fmincon.

```
[X]=model(y(1),y(2))
```

My goal is to optimize y(1) & y(2) subject to constraint on X.
Code:

```
global X
y=[3, 2];
[soln, fval] = fmincon(@obj,y,[],[],[],[],[1, 1],[6, 10],@constraint);

function [c, ceq] = Constraint(x)
global X
c(1)=X(1,1)^2+X(2,1)^2+X(3,1)^2
ceq=[];
```

UPDATED with:

```
function f=obj(y)
f=@(y)model(y(1), y(2))
```

For this code I am getting following error

```
Attempted to access X(1,1); index out of bounds because size(X)=[0,0].
```

What is wrong here? is there any other way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: First could you share on which line it is. Also is X a matrix, vector or scalar? Thirdly your 'model' function should be defined as [X] = model(y), where y is 2 dimensional vector, instead of having two variables in order to work in this manner with fmincon.

Comment: @Belov, it gives me reference to line (38) in model.p file which I can not access. the model function line is not a part of my code currently. Do I need to separately write the function? X is a matrix (3 x 5).

Comment: Try this, although its a shot in the dark. f = @(y) model(y(1),y(2)); and pass @f to fmincon instead.

Comment: Normally assinging to a single variable would just be done like this: `X=model(y(1),y(2))`. Are you able to call `model` succesfully in any way, and what are the inputs then?

Comment: @Belov: I added it. But now it gives me following error,Attempted to access X(1,1); index out of bounds because size(X)=[0,0].

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I could call the model.p using the method suggested by Belov. And now I'm getting above error size(X)=[0,0].

Comment: @user3125389 If you changed the line in the way he suggested you won't assign anything to `X`. Its not strange that you cannot access it then.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin how to evaluate the matrix X? because only then my constraint will be tested. thanks

Comment: @user3125389 why `X` is global? why don't you use `x` that is passed to `constraint` and `obj` by the solver?

Comment: After fmincon finishes, use X=fval instead. This is presuming that what X is the output of the function model evaluated at the minimum point, which to my understanding it is.